# Wordpress 5.5 Lazy Loading on Custom img Tags

Tags: html, wordpress, lazy-loading

Is there anyway to trigger the Wordpress 5.5 Lazy Loading feature on custom img tags?

[This article](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/14/lazy-loading-images-in-5-5/) mentions that "By default, WordPress will add loading="lazy" to all img tags that have width and height attributes present."

When I try to add an image through wp_get_attachment_image() it does add the loading="lazy" and srcset attributes, however when I try to add a plain img tag with the width and height set, these attributes are not being added. Is there an additional class that needs to be set in order to trigger the lazy loading? Or is there something else needed?

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/" alt="placeholder" width="300" height="110">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to manually add the `loading="lazy"` attribute to your images in the HTML / code when you are adding them, similar to how you add the height and width, e.g.

```
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/" 
     alt="placeholder" 
     width="300" 
     height="110"
     loading="lazy"
 >
```

**Browser Support**

Many browsers support the lazy loading, but not all do - you can check here for [Browser Support for lazy loading attribute](https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr)

**Reference for Wordpress support**

As the [WP 5.5. Development update says](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/14/lazy-loading-images-in-5-5/), WordPress 5.5 will add a loading="lazy" attribute to the following images:

- images within post content (`the_content`)
- images within post excerpts (`the_excerpt`)
- images within text widgets (`widget_text_content`)
- avatar images (`get_avatar`)
- template images using `wp_get_attachment_image()` (`wp_get_attachment_image`)

You will need to manually add it yourself for any images that are not added in this way.

Comment: Oh okay. I tried that but it didn't add the srcset attribute like it does if you pull them in from wp_get_attachment_image() so I wasn't sure if they were actually getting lazy-loaded.

Comment: @kierrapalmer Lazy loading and srcset are not related, WP does add both, but that is to add two different functions to image processing. If lazy loading is not working for you, check the support for your browser. not all browsers support the lazy loading attribute yet, I've added a link in the answer that is kept up-to-date with the latest browser support for the attribute.